# Vue cant pass params on this.$router.push

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, quasar-framework

I cant pass params from one component page that redirects to another page.
I have a confirmation that does some process of validation and redirects the user to the login page. In this case i want to display a message on the login page.

My confirmation page code that uses `this.$router.push` to redirect.

```js
methods: {
    async confirmSignUp() {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'Login page', params: {data: '1'} })
     ...
   }
},
async created() {
  await this.confirmSignUp()
}
```

My router code

```js
  {
    // student login
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: () => import('layouts/student/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '/login', name: 'Login page', component: () => import('pages/student/LogInPage.vue')}
    ],
    meta: { preventLoginUser: true },
    props: true
  },
```

My login page code

```js
  mounted() {
    let data = this.$route
    console.log('data is', data)
  },
```

Here i'm just logging the response from the whole router and i'm getting an empty object from params.

```
fullPath: "/login"
hash: ""
href: "/login"
matched: (2) [{…}, {…}]
meta: {preventLoginUser: true}
name: "Login page"
params: {}
path: "/login"
query: {}
redirectedFrom: undefined
```

Note that i'm using Quasar framework

Answer (score 0):

In your router file, you are using the same path for both the parent and child route, remove the `/` from the child component otherwise, it will be treated as the root path.

```js
{
    // student login
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: () => import('layouts/student/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: 'login', name: 'Login page', component: () => import('pages/student/LogInPage.vue')}
    ],
    meta: { preventLoginUser: true },
    props: true
  },
```

> Note that this will generate the route as `/login/login`.

If you need to use `/login`, change the child route as

```js
{
    // student login
    path: '/login',
    component: () => import('layouts/student/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', name: 'login', component: () => import('pages/student/LogInPage.vue')}
    ],
    meta: { preventLoginUser: true },
    props: true
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

#### How to use

You only need to use the `children` key when you want to create nested routes for a parent route. If you are defining a single route, like in this case, then the use of the children key is unnecessary. So in the above example, you can define the `path`, `name`, `component`, and `meta` parameters as follows:

```js
{
  path: '/login',
  name: 'login',
  component: () => import('layouts/student/LogInPage.vue'),
  meta: { preventLoginUser: true },
  props: true
}
```

Call it:

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'login' }); // because "name: 'login'" in route
```

##### Parameters in Route

I don't know what your "data" parameter means in your example. If you want to use a variable in the route, you need to do it like this:

```js
{
  path: '/login/:myparameter',
  name: 'login',
  component: () => import('layouts/student/LogInPage.vue'),
  meta: { preventLoginUser: true },
  props: true
}
```

Call it:

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'login', params: { myparameter: '1' } });
```

##### Run function before call Route --> "Guard"

If the purpose of the parameter was to check whether the user who calls it is logged in, then there is a better solution for that. You can declare your own logic before every route to determine how the route should run. For example, for the `/login` route, if you want it to automatically redirect to the `/admin` route if the user is already logged in.

```js
// in this code, the isLoggedIn() declare your authentication logic, return true if logged and false if not

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: () => import('layouts/student/LogInPage.vue'),
    meta: { preventLoginUser: true },
    props: true
  },
  // ...
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // if call "login", but logged
  if (to.name === 'login' && isLoggedIn()) {
    // redirect to "admin"
    next('/admin')
  }
  // if not...
  else {
    // continue redirect to called route
    next()
  }
})
```

[Example from Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#optional-third-argument-next)

##### Why need MainLayout.vue?

There is a significant difference between `Layout` and `Page`. I would put them in separate folders from the beginning: `/layouts` and `/pages`.

If `MainLayout.vue` is a global layout for all your pages, then you can include it separately in `LogInPage.vue`.

[By Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html)

##### CamelCase name

Something else I noticed is that the `name` attribute is always just a name that you can refer to this route later. So you don't have to remember the URL addresses for the operations, you just request the route named `login`. If the route name is `Login Page`, it's harder to remember off the top of your head, and you're just making things harder for yourself.

If you still need to use multi-word names, it is worth considering omitting spaces and using the `CamelCase` format, such as `loginPage`.